# Selenium WebDriver wait doesn't work with expected conditions for cookie policy window

Tags: python, selenium, browser, conditional-statements

I am trying to get rid of a cookie policy window in selenium which pops-up in the forefront of the web-page I am trying to access. Trying to close it is impossible even using `Expected conditions`. 
I have tried with `element_to_be_clickable` and `presence_of_element_located`, but none of them works.

The strange thing is that when I execute the command of closing the window 10 seconds later, it works. But then why doesn't the `WebDriver wait` command work in this case ? 
Another strange thing is that I don't get this cookie policy window when the selenium tab is open, only when it's reduced.

Finally, according to what I have read, `presence_of_element_located` is the "longest" expected condition in order to find an element in a webpage. So I am quite blocked on that point.

The error  I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 51, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a id="profilelogin" href="https://accounts.marketwatch.com/login?ifr=1&amp;target=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.marketwatch.com%2Fwatchlist">...</a> is not clickable at point (38, 16). Other element would receive the click: <div id="cx-notification-wrapper" class="gdpr-message">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.18.0-17-generic x86_64)
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/code.py", line 91, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 56, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 80, in click
    self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webelement.py", line 633, in _execute
    return self._parent.execute(command, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <a id="profilelogin" href="https://accounts.marketwatch.com/login?ifr=1&amp;target=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.marketwatch.com%2Fwatchlist">...</a> is not clickable at point (38, 16). Other element would receive the click: <div id="cx-notification-wrapper" class="gdpr-message">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.131)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578700 (2f1ed5f9343c13f73144538f15c00b370eda6706),platform=Linux 4.18.0-17-generic x86_64)
```

So my questions are: 1) Why do I get this cookie policy window only when the tab is open 
2) Why are the expected conditions and wait statements not working 
3) (Eventually) How could I get my code working correctly ?

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you very much

My code is the following:

```
driver.get("https://www.marketwatch.com/watchlist")

WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "gdpr-close")))
driver.find_element_by_class_name('gdpr-close').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "wl-scrim-start")))
driver.find_element_by_id('wl-scrim-start').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "gdpr-close")))
driver.find_element_by_class_name('gdpr-close').click()

WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "profilelogin")))
driver.find_element_by_id('profilelogin').click()
```

with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are waiting for the cookie policy close button twice. Your code closes the cookie policy panel first time so it keeps waiting for the button to be clickable again but it is not going to be clickable after you have closed it. That is why you are getting exception.

Try the following:

```py
driver.get("https://www.marketwatch.com/watchlist")

wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME,"gdpr-close"))).click()

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "wl-scrim-start"))).click()

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "profilelogin"))).click()
```

It will take you to the login page without any exception.